# rename file with zmv

Tags: zsh, batch-rename

I just discovered zmv this morning.

To test it i have created a few files.

```
test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

I'm trying to rename them with zmv
I'd like to get this output:

```
test-1.txt test-2.txt test-3.txt
```

when I try to use wildcards I get an error message:

```
zmv '(*)([0-9]{1,})(.txt)' '$1-$2$3'
zmv: error: number of wildcards in each pattern must match
```

Am i doing something wrong (answer has to be yes :) )

Comment: If the first parameter is a regular expression and it is greedy by default, try `([^0-9]*)` as the first part maybe.

Comment: What zsh version? Do you have `zmv` aliased?

Comment: zsh 4.3.9, autoload -U zmv, alias zmv="noglob zmv -W"

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: It's not that it's greedy by default (backtracking takes care of what I think you're trying to fix).  The problem is that `*` is applying to `(`, since he wrote `*` instead of `.*`.  That's probably why zmv thinks there aren't enough capturing groups.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extra-ordinarily late reply since I also ran into this problem and was breaking my head over it. I finally figured out that the zsh customization layer I used (yadr) was aliasing zmv. `alias zmv="noglob zmv -W"`. I believe even the popular oh-my-zsh layer does htis.

Check whether your zmv is aliased. If so unalias it using `unalias zmv` and that horrible `number of wildcards must match` error should disappear now

Answer (score 2):

Do you only want to add a `-` to the filename? Try it like this:

```
zmv -n 'test(*).txt' 'test-${1}.txt'
```

The `-n` switch shows you what would happen without really performing any action.

Comment: Tried just that, but I get the same error message. I'm running zsh 4.3.9 on osx. not sure if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the first arg is supposed to be a regex, the problem is probably that you used `*` instead of `.*`.  (`*` is the 0-or-more operator, `.` matches any single character).

So the first paren probably got taken literally as the arg of the `*` operator, instead of opening a capture group.

Try out http://www.regexr.com/ for an interactive regex tutorial / tester / builder thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another super late reply but because none of the above answers seemed to answer the question for me, here's an answer (using zsh 5.8).

```
❯ ls
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt
```

If I try to run your command I get a different error.  Not sure if that's a much newer version of zsh or that your problem was an alias as suggested above.

```
❯ zmv -n '(*)([0-9]{1,})(.txt)' '$1-$2$3'
zmv:239: no matches found: (*)([0-9]{1,})(.txt)
```

The problem is the `{1,}`. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve with it?

If you want to only match files with a single digit, then you can do this (`-n` shows you what it would do without actually changing anything):

```
❯ zmv -n '(*)([0-9])(.txt)' '$1-$2$3'
mv -- test1.txt test-1.txt
mv -- test2.txt test-2.txt
mv -- test3.txt test-3.txt
```

If you want to match one or more digits, then you can do this:

```
> zmv -n '(*)([0-9]*)(.txt)' '$1-$2$3'
mv -- test1.txt test-1.txt
mv -- test2.txt test-2.txt
mv -- test3.txt test-3.txt
```

Personally I'd write it like this because I think it's clearer:

```
❯ zmv -n '(*)([0-9].txt)' '$1-$2'
mv -- test1.txt test-1.txt
mv -- test2.txt test-2.txt
mv -- test3.txt test-3.txt
```

Or simplest and most obvious of all:

```
❯ zmv -n 'test(*).txt' 'test-$1.txt'
mv -- test1.txt test-1.txt
mv -- test2.txt test-2.txt
mv -- test3.txt test-3.txt
```